# Stucked up in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, scheduler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu0ph.png)

```
for(var j=0;j<$scope.all_date.length;j++) {
    var events = [{
        id: '',
        color: 'red',
        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
        titleDateFormat: '',
        content:'Holiday',
        startDate: new Date($scope.all_date[j].date)
    }];
}
```

In this code i have to set the holiday as content for the relevant dates from the backend.This code only shows the last storage date as holiday.But i have to show all days in back end as holiday till loop ends.

[Front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu0ph.png)
[Back End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHGL.jpg)

Comment: attach html and make a snippet; that way we can easily help.

Comment: You are reassigning `var events` at every step of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var events = [];
for(var j = 0; j< $scope.all_date.length; j++) {
   var event = {
      id: '',
      color: 'red',
      borderColor: '#d2e04f',
      titleDateFormat: '',
      content:'Holiday',
      startDate: new Date($scope.all_date[j].date)
   };

   events.push(event);
}
```

Comment: By your code now iam getting the first date in my db as holiday.What i have to do for getting the whole dates as holiday.

Comment: sorry, then I donr understand what do you need, you must expplain better

Comment: Obviously, the OP is not experienced using `JavaScript`. Provide an explanation as to what your code actually does, if you feel really helpful.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu0ph.png please see this.It will happens after Your code.But i want to show the date holiday for the all days in db https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHGL.jpg

Comment: I think that you need to show as entire function! my part of code creates object with all holidays.. you need to use that object on proper way to fill it in calendar.. I dont see other code so I dont know what are you doing, you are using only one  part of object not all, maybe use on my object for or each loop

Comment: @AngelPolitis thanks for editing :)

Comment: You're welcome @Zeljka

Comment: But how to repeat the events?? @ Zeljka,@ Angel Politis

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new object for every iteration. Though currently is it creating a new object for every loop but it getting overwritten by current value.

Use [array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which will return a new array of objects

```
$scope.all_date.map(function(item){
   var events={
        id: '',
        color: 'red',
        borderColor: '#d2e04f',
        titleDateFormat: '',
        content:'Holiday',
        startDate: new Date($scope.all_date[j].date)
    }
       return events;

})
```

Comment: Only one date is shown as holiday in Alloy_scheduler[Calender] I have to iterate the events for the all.date.length times.How it will be done?? Please give some idea or code for it.

Comment: @Harish please share your `scope.all_date` `json`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHGL.jpg this dates are get from db as scope.all_date.